# Разные темы/оформление для разных доменов одного сайта на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, домен

Как отобразить разные шаблоны тем сайта на WordPress для разных доменов?
Весь контент из одной базы.

Например:

1. site1.ru - тема1.
2. site2.ru - тема2.
3. Контент единый.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень хорошое решение, но можно сделать так в wp-config.php, в зависимости от домена подключать разные настройки темы:

```
 if(strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'site1.ru') !== false){
        define('WP_HOME', 'http://site1.ru');
        define('WP_CURRENT_THEME', 'Тема сайта 1');
        define('TEMPLATEPATH', 'Путь к теме');
        define('STYLESHEETPATH', 'Путь к теме');
    }
```

Аналогчично с второй. Не забудьте стандартные закоментировать.
Также можно поиграть с флажками в БД в зависимости от домена, но это будет намного больше по времени.